# Corda - problem while executing flow with multiple output states

Tags: blockchain, corda

I'm trying to execute a corda flow with 3000 output states (*Java*) but I got the error:

```
[Thread-8 (ActiveMQ-IO-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$4@6a8da5c5)] impl.JournalImpl.run - appendAddRecord::java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Record is too large to store 18603342 {}
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Record is too large to store 18603342
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.switchFileIfNecessary(JournalImpl.java:2915) ~[artemis-journal-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.appendRecord(JournalImpl.java:2640) ~[artemis-journal-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl.access$200(JournalImpl.java:88) ~[artemis-journal-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.journal.impl.JournalImpl$1.run(JournalImpl.java:778) [artemis-journal-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase$ExecutorTask.run(ProcessorBase.java:53) [artemis-commons-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_181]
```

To avoid this problem I divided the execution of the flow into more steps and call it n times (in this case 6) processing 500 output states in every execution.

This solution works, but there is a better/efficient solution to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that a message you are trying to send exceeds the network's max message size.

As of Corda 3.x, this max message size is hardcoded to 10MB (10,485,760 bytes).

In a future version of Corda, the network operator will be able to configure the max message size for the network as part of the network parameters.

The purpose of setting a max message size is to prevent large nodes from bullying smaller nodes by forcing them to process excessively large messages.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response. So the solution adopted is the best one?

Comment: It would really depend on the use-case, and whether you really need to create 3,000 states in a single transaction.